# Check values of multiple categorical columns at a same time

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have multiple categorical columns like Marital Status, Education, Gender, City and I wanted to check all the unique values inside these columns at once instead of writing this code every time.

```
df['Education'].value_counts()
```

I can only give an example of a few features but I need a solution when there are so many categorical features and its not possible to write code again and again to examine them.

```
Maritial_Status Education City
Married         UG        LA
Single          PHD       CA
Single          UG        Ca
```

Expected output:

```
Maritial_Status   Education  City
Married        1  UG       2 LA  1 
Single         2  PHD      1 CA  2
```

Is there any kind of method to do this in Python?
Thanks

Comment: kindly provide sample dataframe with expected output

Comment: check the updated question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get what you're looking for with the following approach (also you don't have to worry about if your `df` has more data than the 4 columns you specified):

1. Get (only) all your categorical columns from your `df` in a `list`:

```
cat_cols = [i for i in df.columns if df[i].dtypes == 'O']
```

2. Then, run a `loop` performing `.size()` on your grouped object, over your categorical columns, and store each result (which is a `df` object) in an empty `list`.

```
li = []
for col in cat_cols:
    li.append(df.groupby([col]).size().reset_index(name=col+'_count'))
```

3. Lastly, `concat` the newly created `dataframes` within your list, into 1.

```
dat = pd.concat(li,axis=1)
```

**All in 1 block**:

```
cat_cols = [i for i in df.columns if df[i].dtypes == 'O']

li = []
for col in cat_cols:
    li.append(df.groupby([col]).size().reset_index(name=col+'_count'))

dat = pd.concat(li,axis=1)# use axis=1, so that the concatenation is column-wise

  Marital Status  Marital Status_count  ...       City  City_count
0       Divorced                   4.0  ...     Athens           4
1        Married                   3.0  ...     Berlin           2
2         Single                   3.0  ...     London           2
3        Widowed                   2.0  ...   New York           2
4            NaN                   NaN  ...  Singapore           2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `value_counts`, you can do the following

```
res = (df
       .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()) # column by column value_counts would be applied
       .stack()
       .reset_index(level=0).sort_index(axis=0)
       .rename(columns={'level_0': 'Value', 0: 'value_counts'}))
```

[image]

#### Another format of the the output:

```
res['Id'] = res.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
res.set_index('Id', append=True)
```

[image]

#### Explanation:

After applying `value_counts`, you will get the following:

[image]

Then using [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) you can remove the `NAN` and get all things "stacked up" and then you can do the formatting/ ordering of the output.

Comment: I believe this is not the expected output?

Comment: Yes, but i think expected output has been given just for demo purpose. His expectation is see all the value counts at one place in one go

Answer (score 0):

To know how many repeated unique values you have for each column, you can try drop_duplicates() method:

```
dataset.drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: thanks, I have updated the question with expected output...